# jQuery before produces multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I have a `bootstrap` nav tabs and I want to add tabs dynamically with jQuery. When I click on a button, a `bootstrap modal` shows up where I can pick an option. Once I've selected one, an `ajax` call get the `id` of selected option, it search for full option object and then return the object as `json`. Then a new tab is added, with the name of the option. All good, but if I click one more time on "Add option", it returns me 2 tabs...and if I add one more...returns 3 tabs, an so on!
heres my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="select_opt" class="modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close_op" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Choose option') }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <select name="op" id="op">
                @if (count($language->optionDescriptions))
                    @foreach ($language->optionDescriptions as $optionDescription)
                        <option value="{{ $optionDescription->option->id }}">{{ $optionDescription->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="select_new_opt" data-dismiss="modal">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
    $('#add_opt').click(function () {
        $('#select_opt').css('display', 'block');
        $('.close_op').click( function () {
            $('#select_opt').css('display', 'none');
        });

        $('#select_new_opt').click(function () {
            var option_id = $('#op option:selected').val();

            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ URL::to('options/getOption') }}',
                data: { id : option_id, _token : $('input[name="_token"]').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.nav.nav-tabs #add_option').before('<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#option-'+option_id+'" data-attr-id="'+option_id+'">'+data.option.name+'</a></li>');
                }
            });
       });


   });
```

html TABS:

```
<div class="tab-content options_tab">
<div id="product" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-md-2">{{ __('Optiuni') }}</label>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bind event handler's instead the event handlers, hence on every `click` event of `#add_opt` element `click` handlers are added for  `.close_op` and `#select_new_opt` element.

Move event binding outside the `click` handler.

```
$('#add_opt').click(function() {
    ....
});

$('.close_op').click(function() {
    ...
});

$('#select_new_opt').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

As you are generating elements dynamically, use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*Example*

```
$(document).on('click', ".close_op", function(){
    $('#select_opt').hide();
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Comment: That's it! You're right! It works like a charm now! What a noob mistake! Thank you very much my friend, just saved my day!